# How to connect console application and Windows form application C#

Tags: c#, windows, console

I put all of my input on my console application, and I like it this way. My question is, how can I fix example read input in the console application, and then do something with it in the windows form app? I want both of my applications running at the same time. Console application will be doing something while Win App is doing something else, but if I will want to, I can connect them.

I have tried :

```
Form1 win = new Form1();
win.show();
```

but it didn't work. The window switch I see is stacked, and it is not able to run as it should.

Comment: You'll need ShowDialog().  You are not going to like it, now your console no longer works.  Programming a GUI app is fundamentally different from console apps.  You only get there when you make a clean break from the ways you like and are familiar with.  The brain transplant is going to hurt for a while.

Answer (score 2):

1- Create a winforms application

2- Set output type as a `Console Applcation` by `Project/Properties/Application/Output Type`

Now You have a windows application together with a console

Comment: Yes, I think that's what he was asking for - unless he wants two totally separate processes communicating (seems unlikely given the question)